# Is it possible to create a mobile navigation application with React Native?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, mobile, navigation

How to do navigation application using with google maps and react native?  I want to do a navigation application but I am not sure if this is possible with react native.

What are your recommendations?

Comment: @TwiN Thank you, is it possible in mobile application?

Comment: I want to use like Google maps application direction and navigation on Native application. Is it healthy to do it with web view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible, anything is possible as long as you have the patience to to it.

React is just a JavaScript Framework, if you can make a navigation website using HTML and JS, surely you can make one using React. If you want it to be a standalone (not a web application), you can try using Electron, but I suggest sticking with a web application.

Now, if by application, you mean a mobile application, you can run the website on a web view, so provided the website is mobile friendly, you can use React for that too.

A quick Google search led me to the following results:

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps

Which is a React Native Mapview component for iOS and Android.

There's an image from the repository:

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a library called react-native-google-maps-directions.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-maps-directions

you can easily set your source and destination then it will navigate using the geo coordinates provided.